# How to increment a new column based on values in a specified range [a moving window] of another column in R

Tags: r, excel, data.table, tidyverse

I would like to create new columns based on values in a moving-window range of another column. One of the new column would be based on a moving window from previous rows in another column, while the other column would be based on a moving window from subsequent rows in another column.

Let´s take the following dataset as an example:

```
dt <- data.frame(A_LM = c(0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0,
                          0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0),
                 B_LM = c(1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
                          0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1))
```

I would like to create:

- a column called "A_LM_corrected" detecting when 1s are in A_LM and only keeping those for which no other 1s were in the last 5 previous rows of A_LM. It should consist of 1s when the condition is met and 0 when the condition is not met,
- a column called "B_LM_corrected" with the same principle but for values in column B_LM,
- a column called "A_LM_foll" detecting when 1s are present in A_LM_corrected and only keeping those for which 1s are also present in the next 5 subsequent rows of B_LM_corrected [detecting when 1s are present in A_LM_corrected and in at least 1 of the 5 subsequent rows of B_LM_corrected], and
- a column called "B_LM_foll" with the same principle [detecting when 1s are present in B_LM_corrected and in at least 1 of the 5 subsequent rows of A_LM_corrected].

Ideally, the final data frame would be this one:

```
dt_aim <- data.frame(A_LM = c(0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0,
                              0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0),
                     B_LM = c(1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
                              0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1),
                     A_LM_corrected = c(0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0,
                                        0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0),
                     B_LM_corrected = c(1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
                                        0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1),
                     A_LM_foll = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
                                   0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0),
                     B_LM_foll = c(1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
                                   0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0))
```

I tried to use the `tidyverse` and `data.table` to do so, but I do not manage to get what I need [I am even very far from it].

I know that this is quite easy to be done in Excel:

- Column A [A_LM]: first value of interest in cell A2 (0 in this example)
- Column B [B_LM]: first value of interest in cell B2 (1 in this example)
- Column C [A_LM_corrected] (it has to be incremented for the first 5 rows, afterwards it can just be copied/pasted):

  - C2 = IF(A2 = 1, IF(SUM(A1:A1) > 0, 0, A2), A2)
  - C3 = IF(A3 = 1, IF(SUM(A1:A2) > 0, 0, A3), A3)
  - C4 = IF(A4 = 1, IF(SUM(A1:A3) > 0, 0, A4), A4)
  - C5 = IF(A5 = 1, IF(SUM(A1:A4) > 0, 0, A5), A5)
  - C6 = IF(A6 = 1, IF(SUM(A1:A5) > 0, 0, A6), A6)
  - C7 = IF(A7 = 1, IF(SUM(A2:A6) > 0, 0, A7), A7)
  - C8 = IF(A8 = 1, IF(SUM(A3:A7) > 0, 0, A8), A8)
- Column D [B_LM_corrected] (it has to be incremented for the first 5 rows, afterwards it can just be copied/pasted):

  - D2 = IF(B2 = 1, IF(SUM(B1:B1) > 0, 0, B2), B2)
  - D3 = IF(B3 = 1, IF(SUM(B1:B2) > 0, 0, B3), B3)
  - D4 = IF(B4 = 1, IF(SUM(B1:B3) > 0, 0, B4), B4)
  - D5 = IF(B5 = 1, IF(SUM(B1:B4) > 0, 0, B5), B5)
  - D6 = IF(B6 = 1, IF(SUM(B1:B5) > 0, 0, B6), B6)
  - D7 = IF(B7 = 1, IF(SUM(B2:B6) > 0, 0, B7), B7)
  - D8 = IF(B8 = 1, IF(SUM(B3:B7) > 0, 0, B8), B8)
- column E [A_LM_foll] (copy directly copied/pasted without initial manual incrementation):

  - E2 = IF(C2 = 1, IF(SUM(D3:D7) > 0, 1, 0), 0)
- column F [B_LM_foll] (copy directly copied/pasted without initial manual incrementation):

  - F2 = IF(D2 = 1, IF(SUM(C3:C7) > 0, 1, 0), 0)

But I need to have it work in R ;-)

Any help is welcome :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one possibility using the `tidyverse`.

In particular I use the function `map_dbl` to create help variables `A_LM_back` and `B_LM_back` to check the previous five rows.

```
dt %>% 
  mutate(
    A_LM_back = map_dbl(1:n(), \(k) max(0, A_LM[pmax(k-1:5, 0)])),
    B_LM_back = map_dbl(1:n(), \(k) max(0, B_LM[pmax(k-1:5, 0)])),
  ) %>% 
  mutate(
    A_LM_cor = if_else(A_LM == 1 & A_LM_back == 0, 1, 0),
    B_LM_cor = if_else(B_LM == 1 & B_LM_back == 0, 1, 0),
  ) %>%
  mutate(
    A_LM_next = map_dbl(1:n(), \(k) max(A_LM_cor[pmin(k+1:5, nrow(dt))])),
    B_LM_next = map_dbl(1:n(), \(k) max(B_LM_cor[pmin(k+1:5, nrow(dt))])),
  ) %>% 
  mutate(
    A_LM_foll = if_else(A_LM_cor == 1 & B_LM_next == 1, 1, 0),
    B_LM_foll = if_else(B_LM_cor == 1 & A_LM_next == 1, 1, 0),
  )
```

Comment: Thanks @Cettt. So if I understand correctly, you used map_dbl to apply an anonymous function to each row of the dataset, which aims at finding the max between 0 and the values in the last 5 previous rows [for A_LM_back]. As soon as there is a 1 in these previous rows, there will be a 1 in the current row of A_LM_back. For A_LM_next, nrow(dt) is there to constrain the anymous function to only search up to the last row of the data?

Answer (score 4):

An alternative `dplyr` method using `zoo`:

```r
library(dplyr)
dt %>%
  mutate(
    across(
      ends_with("_LM"),
      ~ +(. > 0 & zoo::rollapplyr(. < 1, list(-(1:4)), all, partial = TRUE, fill = TRUE)),
      .names = "{.col}_corrected"),
    A_LM_foll = +(A_LM_corrected & zoo::rollapply(B_LM_corrected > 0, list(-1:4), any, partial = TRUE, align = "left")),
    B_LM_foll = +(B_LM_corrected & zoo::rollapply(A_LM_corrected > 0, list(-1:4), any, partial = TRUE, align = "left"))
  )
#    A_LM B_LM A_LM_corrected B_LM_corrected A_LM_foll B_LM_foll
# 1     0    1              0              1         0         1
# 2     0    1              0              0         0         0
# 3     0    0              0              0         0         0
# 4     1    1              1              0         0         0
# 5     0    0              0              0         0         0
# 6     0    0              0              0         0         0
# 7     0    0              0              0         0         0
# 8     0    1              0              0         0         0
# 9     0    0              0              0         0         0
# 10    0    0              0              0         0         0
# 11    1    0              1              0         0         0
# 12    0    0              0              0         0         0
# 13    0    0              0              0         0         0
# 14    0    0              0              0         0         0
# 15    0    0              0              0         0         0
# 16    0    0              0              0         0         0
# 17    0    1              0              1         0         1
# 18    0    0              0              0         0         0
# 19    0    0              0              0         0         0
# 20    0    0              0              0         0         0
# 21    1    0              1              0         1         0
# 22    0    0              0              0         0         0
# 23    1    0              0              0         0         0
# 24    0    0              0              0         0         0
# 25    0    1              0              1         0         0
```

Many thanks to @G.Grothendieck for improving the latter two `rollapply`'s, and much more so helping me to understand the use of `list(-(1:4))` in the first `rollapplyr`. For future me: if `width=` is a numeric vector, then its widths apply to each of the `by=` elements, and if it is shorter than the data, it is recycled. However, if `widths=` is a `list`, then its values are considered offsets from the current time, so while `widths=5, align="right"` means `c(-4, -3, -2, -1, 0)` offset from "here", `widths=list(-(1:4)), align="right"` means `c(-4, -3, -2, -1)` from "here", ignoring the `0`th ("here"th) element. Mind blown :-)

Comment: Thanks @r2evans. Really great code, but I do not fully understand the parts with ```+(...)```. What does this do compared to not using +? It seems like its changing logical values [TRUE/FALSE] to their numeric equivalent [1/0]. The part ```A_LM_corrected & zoo::rollapply(B_LM_corrected, 5, \(z) any(z > 0), partial = TRUE, align = "left")``` seems to be understood as verifying whether a condition is met, but how does R know that we are interest in ```A_LM_corrected == 1``` for the condition?

Comment: Inside the `(...)`, the return value is logical. Wrapping a logical vector in `+(..)` is a shortcut for converting it to integers `0:1`.

Comment: @KrisAnathema using `+` instead of `as.numeric()` as I did is generally slightly better performance-wise in that it returns an `integer()` rather than `numeric()` (i.e. float) vector. This may not make a difference depending on the size of your data. I used `as.numeric()` partly because it's slightly more explicit, but mostly because it allowed me to use `identical()` to compare with your expected output without converting the types.

Comment: Thanks @G.Grothendieck! I had started with that and don't know why I shifted away; you're right, a single `x > 0` is much better than repetitive `z > 0`. The shift to `list(-(1:4))` took a bit more research. I've never internalized the (documented) distinction between a vector (length > 1) and a list with a vector, that's awesome to learn! I'll have to practice that a bit more for it to sink in.

Comment: @r2evans, width= is a vector of widths or a list of vectors representing offsets.  In both cases it is the same length as the input (assuming a vector input) and recycled if less.

Comment: Thanks @r2evans and @G.Grothendieck. However, both the previous version and the current one do not match my Excel formula for my own data. The answer from @Cettt works perfectly for me, even though I had to add ```na.rm = TRUE``` to the ```max``` functions. I think the difference comes from the fact that in your code, the current row is also included in the ```rollapply``` function. Which means that if a 1 is in the same row for A_LM_corrected and B_LM_corrected [but B_LM_corrected has only 0 in the following rows], then A_LM_foll will still be 1. But ideally for me it should be 0. Any idea?

Comment: width = list(-(1:4)) means use the previous 4 rows, offsets -1, -2, -3, -4..  The current row is not used.  width=5 uses the current row and the previous 4.

Comment: The code and your `dt` produces your `dt_aim`, so the issue appears to be with your expected output, not much I can do there. That's too bad, @KrisAnathema.

Comment: @KrisAnathema, in case it matters, I changed _all_ `widths=` references to use the `list(-(1:4))`: it still produces the same output here, perhaps it'll work better with your _real_ data.

Comment: Also align= indicates which end of the window is aligned with the current value so if align="left" is used then the left end of the window is aligned with the current value and so width=5 means the current value and the next 4.  If align="right" is used then the right end of the window is aligned with the current value so width=5 means the current value and the prior 4.   Note that rollapplyr with an r on the end defaults to align="right".  This is all explained in the help file ?rollapply and there are many examples there.

Comment: Also If a list is used for the width then it specifies offsets directly so align is ignored.  For example `align="right"` with `width=5` is the same as `width=list(-(4:0))` This is all explained in the help file ?rollapply and there are many examples there.

Comment: I had never tried `width=-5` instead of changing `align=`, thanks.

Comment: There can't be a negative width so `width = -5` is invalid but there can be negative offsets.  `width = list(-5)` means use only the 5th prior value.

Comment: Thanks, when applied to my data, this code now also gives the same output than the one from @Cettt and is identical to what I wanted to compute. I still had to change two elements to make it work: change ```list(-1:4)``` to ```list(1:4)``` in ```A_LM_foll``` and in ```B_LM_foll```. This is because I need this condition to work in subsequent rows rather than in the previous rows.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a `data.table` approach. [`frollsum()`](https://rdrr.io/cran/data.table/man/froll.html) takes the rolling sum of a vector. It works in a slightly surprising way before the start of the vector:

```r
x <- 1:10
SHIFT <- 5
frollsum(x, n = SHIFT, fill = 0)
#  [1]  0  0  0  0 15 20 25 30 35 40
```

I would expect this to return triangle numbers for the first `n` numbers, and then increase at a constant rate of `n`. However, the first `n` numbers take the value of `fill`. If you don't supply a `fill` then they will be `NA`. To get triangle numbers starting from the first index, you need to do this, which I find a little awkward:

```r
frollsum(c(rep(0, SHIFT), x), SHIFT)[(SHIFT + 1):(length(x) + SHIFT)]
#  [1]  1  3  6 10 15 20 25 30 35 40
```

Still I think this should be relatively fast.

```r
library(data.table)
setDT(dt)
sd_cols <- c("A_LM", "B_LM")
SHIFT <- 5

dt[,
    (sprintf("%s_corrected", sd_cols)) := lapply(
        .SD,
        \(x) as.numeric(x == 1 & frollsum(c(rep(0, SHIFT), shift(x)), SHIFT, na.rm = TRUE)[(SHIFT + 1):(.N + SHIFT)] == 0)
    ),
    .SDcols = sd_cols
]

dt[, A_LM_foll := as.numeric(
    A_LM_corrected == 1 & frollsum(c(B_LM_corrected, rep(0, SHIFT)), SHIFT, align = "left", na.rm = TRUE)[1:.N] > 0
)]

dt[, B_LM_foll := as.numeric(
    B_LM_corrected == 1 & frollsum(c(A_LM_corrected, rep(0, SHIFT)), SHIFT, align = "left", na.rm = TRUE)[1:.N] > 0
)]

identical(dt, dt_aim) # TRUE
```